# COM interface modifications have suddenly started causing exceptions

Tags: c#, c++, com, visual-studio-2012

A couple of years ago I inherited a C# app that uses COM objects defined in an unmanaged C++ DLL.  I've been successfully tweaking the object interfaces ever since, but following a (possibly irrelevant) VS2012 upgrade, function signature additions and changes are suddenly being punished by random exceptions such as ExecutionEngineException and SEHException.

My understanding was that the app uses registration-free COM.  There's no DLLRegisterServer implementation, and I see no mention of the interface guids in the registry, just one in C#...

```
[ComImport,
Guid("C2427CB1-D6AE-49e8-B266-114F981C3353"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown),
SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()]
public interface IDC
{
```

and one in a C++ header.

```
interface __declspec(uuid("C2427CB1-D6AE-49e8-B266-114F981C3353"))
IDC : IUnknown
{
```

To be sure though, I decided to swap a new guid into these two places, and discovered that it stopped C# from recognizing the class at all:

```
System.InvalidCastException

Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Apx.IDC'.
This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the
interface with IID '{the new guid}' failed due to the following error:
No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
```

(The above error is apparently often caused by mixing appartment states, but swapping a guid doesn't cause that).  So I deduce there must be additional relevant detail *somewhere* that's conflicting with my changes.  But where might that somewhere be?  Thanks for reading...

Edit:

An example exception is...

```
First-chance exception at 0x000007feec748be4 (clr.dll) in Apex.exe: 0xC0000005:
Access violation reading location 0xffffffffffffffff.
The Common Language Runtime cannot stop at this exception. Common causes include:
incorrect COM interop marshalling, and memory corruption. To investigate further,
using native-only debugging.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Apex.exe
```

for

```
[PreserveSig] [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
bool LoadDisplayList(IntPtr fileHandle, IntPtr pDisplayList,
UInt16 version, IntPtr pComparison);
```

and

```
virtual bool __stdcall LoadDisplayList(HANDLE fileHandle, class CDisplayList * pDisplayList,
WORD version, CDisplayList * pComparison) = 0;
```

with a stack trace ending

```
[Native to Managed Transition]  
Apex.Graphics64.dll!CDisplayList::LoadRenderRecs(void * f=0x000000000000056c, CDisplayList * pComparison=0x0000000023ad2cf0)  Line 1772 C++
Apex.Graphics64.dll!CDisplayList::Load(void * f=0x000000000000056c, unsigned short version=0x0002, CDisplayList * pComparison=0x0000000023ad2cf0)  Line 1845 + 0x26 bytes   C++
Apex.Graphics64.dll!CBaseDC::LoadDisplayList(void * f=0x000000000000056c, CDisplayList * pList=0x0000000023ad2cf0, unsigned short version=0x0002, CDisplayList * pComparison=0x0000000023ad2cf0)  Line 1896 + 0x33 bytes    C++
[Managed to Native Transition]  
Apex.exe!Apex.DDC.LoadDisplayList(System.IO.FileStream file = {System.IO.FileStream}, Apex.DisplayList displayList = {Apex.DisplayList}, ushort version = 0x0002, Apex.DisplayList comparison = null) Line 1124 + 0xaf bytes    C#
Apex.exe!Apex.DisplayList.Load(System.IO.FileStream f = {System.IO.FileStream}, ushort loadVersion = 0x0002, Apex.INode stubsRoot = {Apex.ViewPort3D}, Apex.DisplayList comparison = null) Line 166 + 0x53 bytes    C#
```

The exact crash point varies somewhat - here it actually managed to get inside LoadDisplayList(), which is better than usual.  As the crash suggests heap damage, I've tried stripping the function's signature down to a parameterless void return, reduced its contents to a trace, and called it right after the object's creation - still to get a crash.  The same function doesn't crash if I move it to the top of the definitions, in which case some other interface function crashes out instead, leading me to think it's more likely to be a COM problem than algorithm-level memory corruption.

Comment: to clarify: you have been changing the signatures of the function and exceptions happen when both sides are updated and rebuilt. what are exactly the message of the exceptions and callstacks?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic, sorry, that comment submitted itself!  I've added those details to the description.

Comment: to me it seems that it is a mismatch between interface layouts in different components. I assume that you modify both dlls when you reorder the methods. what about interop dll? if you don't update it too, than the marshalling will fail.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic: Yes, I even built a simple parser to double-check the ordering.  Apart from the C# EXE and C++ DLL, the only other DLL is an ActiveX wrapper for a control inside the EXE.

Comment: One of the rules of COM is to never modify an interface - create a new one instead. That avoids the problems of incompatible versions of an interface blowing things up. See [Designing COM Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809984.aspx), "Interfaces Are Immutable".

Comment: @MarkRansom: There are theoretically no other versions yet, but this was in my mind when I changed the guid.  I don't understand why it was unsuccessful though.

Comment: How can you say there are no other versions? I quote from the beginning of your question: "function signature additions and changes". Each change potentially creates an incompatible version. P.S. You might get some help from [Registration-Free Activation of COM Components: A Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx) step 7.

Comment: Just curious, why are you repeating the interface definitions in C#? That's bad practice. You can just import the type library with the TlbImp.exe utility and it will create an assembly with the correct interface definitions automatically.

Comment: @MarkRansom: By this I mean that the application hasn't been deployed anywhere yet, so until that time I'm expecting any non-current versions to be overwritten daily by the build process.

Comment: To avoid what? Using TlbImp.exe shouldn't affect performance, it's just a way to automatically generate interface definitions that you would otherwise have to write manually.

Comment: @user1610015: Many of the implementation details are historic and very eccentric (runtime doctoring of vtable pointers anyone?).  As the application needs to be blisteringly fast, the idea may have been to eliminate any abstraction inefficiency that TlbImp's lack of detailed knowledge of the consumer might introduce.  I don't know if that's actually based in any reality, I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've fixed the problem. Once I was able to step into the DLL a little, a popup saying that the source didn't match the executable led me to investigate another longstanding but previously unproblematic quirk, that the DLL's Linker / General / Output File wasn't inside the project's General / Output Directory (warning MSB8012). After cleaning up this anomaly I was able change the guid successfully, so it seems VS2012 uses these settings slightly differently to older versions. The moral...don't let warnings hang around.